# Oracle Check Constraint Issue with to_date

Tags: sql, oracle

So I'm new to Oracle, trying to create a table as follows:

```
create table Movies (
   Title   varchar2 primary key,
   Rating NUMBER CONSTRAINT Rating_CHK CHECK (Rating BETWEEN 0 AND 10),
   Length NUMBER CONSTRAINT Length_CHK CHECK (Length > 0),
   ReleaseDate DATE CONSTRAINT RDATE_CHK
               CHECK (ReleaseDate > to_date('1/1/1900', 'DD/Month/YYYY')),
   CONSTRAINT title_pk PRIMARY KEY (Title)
)
```

Per my assignment, the ReleaseDate must have a constraint enforcing only dates after 1/1/1900.  The input my professor has given us for dates is as follows:  13 August 2010

Can one of you experts see where my issue lies?

Comment: The error message and your SQL would make sense, But I would guess you didn't parse the input string of your prof correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spec for Title column is incorrect, as well as the date string/format model combination in your to_date function call. Specify a column length for TITLE, and fix the date string to match the format model.

Try this:

```
create table Movies (
   Title   varchar2(100),
   Rating NUMBER CONSTRAINT Rating_CHK CHECK (Rating BETWEEN 0 AND 10),
   Length NUMBER CONSTRAINT Length_CHK CHECK (Length > 0),
   ReleaseDate date CONSTRAINT RDATE_CHK CHECK (ReleaseDate > to_date('1/January/1900', 'DD/Month/YYYY')),
   CONSTRAINT title_pk PRIMARY KEY (Title)
)
```

Update:
As an aside, Title is a lousy primary key. Ever hear of two different movies with the same title? Can you say "remake"?

Another edit. I guess since your prof gave you the date format, you should make the date string match the format model. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Agreed - sadly I didn't make it clear enough in my description, but this question is based off of a homework assignment - Professor came up with the primary key and constraints.

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I needed. I'm about to post one more question, if you are feeling generous and want to help out a beginner one more time : )

Comment: I'm sure SOMEBODY here will help you ;-)

Comment: You can look like a Really Smart Guy by pointing out in class why title is a poor PK ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think 'Month' in TO_DATE is looking for a month name - not a number.
Either change the second 1 to January or change Month to MM.